# How can I switch the current user from within a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, passwords

I have to write a shell script to run some commands on unix. I have to switch several users.
How can I give passwords inside my script?

Note: I am not a root user. Also, security is not an issue in this case, so I could write passwords in my script.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have root access, and assuming the programs you want to run aren't setuid, you have two basic choices:

1. Write an [expect script](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to drive `su - <username>` and run your commands as child processes of expect.
2. Have someone with root access give you [sudo access](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/) to the commands and users you need, and then run your commands with `sudo -u <username> <command>`.

Option 1 is best if you can't get administrative support, but option 2 is more flexible and easier to script from a Unix shell.